# What does CAQ stand for, in relation to cosmetics?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, acronyms

I recently received a mascara product from Korea. On the top of the product it says "CAQ 20150209".

I did check out the [acronymfinder](http://www.acronymfinder.com/CAQ.html), but most of them have nothing to do with cosmetics. I guess it might be "Certificate of Adequate Qualifications". But how does this relate to the date?

My question is, what does CAQ stand for in this case? Does it mean it's produced in 20150209? Thanks.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.organicconsumers.org/old_articles/bodycare/bodycare_cosmetics.php) appear to be related?

Comment: You mean "Certificate of Added Qualification "

Comment: @MattGutting If it is related, that product is certainly a long way from home.

Answer (score 1):

CAQ - Computer Aided quality assurance

Computer-aided quality assurance (CAQ) is the engineering application of computers and computer controlled machines for the definition and inspection of the quality of products.

This includes:

Measuring equipment management
Goods inward inspection
Vendor rating
Attribute chart
Statistical process control (SPC)
Documentation

From http://www.ibs-ag.de/ibs-produktions-und-qualitaetsmanagement-glossar/glossarbegriff/glossary-detail/caq-computer-aided-quality-assurance/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How does this relate to the date?